# Can "rm -rf" on a docker container delete files on the host?

Tags: python, docker, file

I have a docker image that consists of a python script, which takes some arbitrary source code and `eval()`'s it

Let's say the code was `rm -rf`. Would this delete anything on the *host's* file system?

I think the answer is "no", but I just want to confirm before trying it out.

Comment: only if you're sharing the dir you run that in with the host OS?

Comment: Mike I have `WORKDIR /usr/src/app` in my Dockerfile but I don't see this in my file system.

Comment: Don't tell me, tell everyone by updating your post. If you don't have sharing turned on for your docker image, then nothing you do in your docker image affects your host os.

Comment: Depends on whether you have `VOLUME`s defined. One certainly *can* set up Docker to have access to the host filesystem, but it needs to be a deliberate act. Does that mean Docker is a secure enough execution environment to run arbitrary, deliberately hostile code? Absolutely not -- but most of the time, that hostile code will need to do something more intricate to break out of its sandbox, before it can start messing with the host.

Comment: However, this question as a whole is off-topic; it isn't about *writing software*, which is Stack Overflow's sole scope. Security has the separate site [security.se]; system administration has the separate site [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/); general UNIX tool-and-semantic questions belong on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Stack Overflow is **only** for specific, narrow questions about problems you actually encounter during the process of writing code.

Comment: ...back to the topic of the question, though -- the thing to keep in mind is that all Docker containers are sharing your host's kernel. Privilege escalation or namespace-escape bugs in the kernel thus are fair game; unlike a proper virtual machine, which has a separate kernel from the host's. (Even then, the emulation stacks in proper virtual machines still have bugs from time to time -- but it's still generally more work to exploit those than it is to leverage a kernel bug somewhere there's a known one out that hasn't yet been patched).

Comment: (...and remember, kernel patches don't take effect unless you reboot, so for purposes of many of the bugs that can be used to attack the host from within Docker containers, it doesn't do you any good to be up-to-date according to apt/yum/pacman/etc. if you haven't actually rebooted since the last kernel update that was applied).

Comment: @Charles thanks for explanation! The thing I don't quite understand is: given that container is part of the OS, if the container executes `rm -rf *`, how does it *not* wipe out the host OS as well?

Comment: The container only has access to a restricted set of namespaces. As Docker configures those namespaces during container startup, its `/` points to a different location from the host's `/`. Are you familiar with how `chroot` works? It's very much like that, just covering a larger set of namespaces

Comment: The kernel extensions that made Docker possible introduced not just filesystem namespaces (which let one not just restrict a child to a smaller set of namespaces, but actually *have its own mount table*, so it can have things mounted the root namespace does not), IPC namespaces (to isolate traditional UNIX inter-process communication), user namespaces (so different UIDs can have different meanings), and so forth. So it's all one kernel, *but* syscalls invoked in different namespaces are looking at different views of the data.

Comment: On the other hand, an attacker who finds a kernel bug that lets them run arbitrary code or otherwise read and update arbitrary values can just switch their process's namespace pointer over to the root's, and suddenly they have access to everything.

Comment: Anyhow, the details of exactly how a container's filesystem namespaces are set up depend on which backends a given install of Docker is configured to use; there's no one generic explanation that's always true, so I'm hesitant to go into any details here.

Answer (score 2):

So on the one hand, yes, Docker's filesystem isolation means that commands like `rm -rf` by default can't do more than corrupt the container's filesystem.

There's a fairly wide variety of things people do routinely that weaken this.  Do you bind-mount your host's source code into the container to simplify development?  Malicious code could corrupt your development tree, or surreptitiously slip commits into your `.git` directory.  Bind-mount the Docker socket into the container so you can launch other containers?  It's trivial to take advantage of that to root the whole host.

This is also just a narrow slice of what's possible with `eval()`.  Linux kernel exploits happen fairly regularly, and since Docker containers share the host kernel, `eval()`ed code could take advantage of this.  There are also things like cryptocurrency miners that aren't dangerous *per se* but you still don't want to be running them for other people.

As far as your narrow question goes, yes, Docker gives you protection from malicious code corrupting the host filesystem, but there are still a lot of other things malicious code could do and I would not try to use a Docker container as a sandbox for truly untrusted code.